# Twitter share button not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter, share

I am working on a social share button on my site.It was working fine but at some point of time it started to show nothing.
I am attaching [my script file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0m3tuprddqkvus/scripts.js?dl=0) which has all script in it for sharing . I am very bad in jquery. Link to my [staging](http://staging.thewindow.barneys.com/the-22-best-menswear-pieces-for-that-spring-getaway/) site .Under Facebook share icon twitter should appear.
the below code has  **share: {
          twitter: true
        },**

I turned that to false and did not work .The funny part is I replaced **twitter** to **facebook:true** inside **share: {
          facebook:true
        },** and it started appearing and i am able to share on twitter.But thats not a solution.What else could be the error that is happening .Please help

```
<script>
      var twitterSettings = $.extend({}, smShareDefaults, {
    share: {
      twitter: true
    },
    buttons: { twitter: {via: 'BarneysNY'}},
    click: function(api, options){
      track( 'Social Share', 'Twitter', document.title );
      api.simulateClick();
      api.openPopup('twitter');
    }
  } );
  $('.sm-share.twitter').sharrre(twitterSettings);
</script>
```

Comment: I had same problem with twitter share button. I saw share button link in fire bug there was missing language eg. en_US. I put it static and share button is  visible for me.

Comment: Your staging site link is broken, but other pages have the twitter button. Do you still have a problem? If so, please provide a link with a problem / JsFiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I go to your staging site, I try this in console

`$(".sm-share.twitter")` that results in `[]`

meaning that there is no button attached to the lib.

Can you please specify where the button should be printed by the Sharrre lib ?

Comment: I paused the script execution, I added manually the sm-share div

with `$('<div class="sm-share twitter"></div>').appendTo('body')`

and it worked (on your staging site)

Comment: Your staging link is giving 404 Page not found, clicking on a story goes to an article with the twitter button working. Did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your network settings ? may be your network administrator have blocked twitter over your network.

you should check you logs in console for any error if any.

Comment: it's very unlikely that twitter is blocked in a media company, but why not